# Concatenate db values on rows

Tags: php, rows, concatenation

I'd like to concatenate this db values into one rows but i failed to do so. Can anyone help me regarding this problem? Thanks much!

```
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i;$i++; ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vfname'. " " & 'vmname' & " " & 'vlname']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vage']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vprecinct']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vworkstat']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vleaders']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vclass']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vaddress']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vcontact']); ?></td>
            <td><?php print($row['vdatereg']); ?></td>    
            </tr>
```

Comment: `$row["vfname"]` is probably a value from your database. Whatever you've got there is not. `&` is a binary math operator...

Comment: each value needs to be accessed from the `$row` array -> `print($row['vfname']." " .$row['vmname']." " .$row['vlname']);`

Comment: already fixed it sir. i concat it in sql statement

Answer (score 1):

done. i concat it in the sql statement hope this will help anyone

```
$tablecontent = '';
                                    $start = '';
                                    $selectStmt = $con->prepare("SELECT vaddress, Concat(vfname, ' ', vmname, ' ', vlname) AS Name, vage, vcontact, vworkstat, vclass, vprecinct, vleaders, vdatereg FROM votersinfotbl ORDER BY vaddress ASC");
                                    $selectStmt->execute();
                                    $votersinfotbl = $selectStmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Doing in a Better Tool (or more appropriate) is often the more efficient way anyway

Comment: would you mind orient me on that way sir? so interested to learn a lot ways to do it.

Comment: You've done it yourself using the concat() in SQL - although pulling the columns and appending the strings in the print statements would be just as quick.  One of the good examples though is comparing results between a DB and an array.  The array has to end up in a db eventually, so I put it there first and use the DB engine to compare the 2 tables vs looping through both massive arrays (50k records in each).